# Parsing Json Using Retrofit gives null

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I am trying to get data from Json using Retrofit2, but I am getting null.
I am not sure what should I put in Interface GET method?

Json Datum response:

```
public class DatumResponse {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;
@SerializedName("total")
@Expose
private Integer total;

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Integer getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(Integer total) {
    this.total = total;
}
```

Retrofit class

```
public class JsonApi {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.deezer.com";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

And my Interface:

```
public interface IDatum {

@GET("chart")
Call<DatumResponse> getDatum();
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you getting response null or some data null? Your interface seems ok if you are aspecting some response in DatumResponse format calling this url ***https://api.deezer.com/charts*** i thinks you are missing last "/" on BASE_URL

Comment: change `https://api.deezer.com` to `https://api.deezer.com/`

Comment: I am getting null, I need to get top 10 tracks from json.

Comment: @AliAhmed Added but still nothing

Comment: your JSON Response is not right. you should add all model classes and then get tracks out of them

Comment: I have added Datum.class, Album.class, Artist.class, i could not post them, they are too big.

Comment: you are missing the parent "tracks" of data. The JSON response start with `{
"tracks": {
"data": [`

Comment: @justo can you give me advice how to do that?

Comment: you can put your response here http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ then remove unecessary items

Comment: @justo I  used  jsonschema2pojo.org and all classes it generated are in my project

Comment: do you have "tracks" class?

Comment: No, It does not generate that class. I have Album, Artist, Datum, DatumResponse. Not sure how to add it manualy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184079/discussion-between-justo-and-toni0123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add complete json to [JsonScheme2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) you will get these classes

[image]

Here **TrackDetailsModel** is Main Model Class. using this you can get other data.

Now change

```
@GET("chart")
Call<DatumResponse> getDatum();
```

To

```
@GET("chart")
Call<TrackDetailsModel> getDatum();
```

Get data using this

```
ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

Call<TrackDetailsModel> call = apiInterface.getDatum();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<TrackDetailsModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<TrackDetailsModel> call, Response<TrackDetailsModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                 TrackDetailsModel model = response.body();
                 String trackTitle = model.getTracks().getData().getTitle();

                    }
                }

    @Override
    public void onFailure (Call <TrackDetailsModel> call, Throwable t){
          call.cancel();
          Toast.makeText(Main.this,"Error: " + t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I am not sure, but adding my json does not provide me all that. https://api.deezer.com/chart

Comment: have you added JSON got from `api.deezer.com/chart` to `jsonScheme2pojo`?

Comment: @Toni0123 when you open [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) there will be `Class name` on Right Top, Change that from *Example* to *TrackDetailsModel* . Then add your all json (that you got from `api.deezer.com/chart` to Text Section on Left.) *Must Remember* Source Type should be **JSON** and Annotation style should be **GSON**. Then at bottom press *Preview*. you will get all Model Classes. add those to your project

Comment: Thanks, I will try :)

Comment: Tried, but it does not work.    Call<TrackDetailsModel> call = IApiClient.getDatum(); needs to be static,

Comment: `IApiClient` is object of Retrofit Interface ?  see my update. Do it as i have done

Comment: I have done like that before but I am getting: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void retrofit2.Call.enqueue(retrofit2.Callback)' on a null object reference, also .getTitle() cant be found and I have all classes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184087/discussion-between-ali-ahmed-and-toni0123).